# JS - what kind of object is it and how can I access it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm playing with reactjs and have problems processing an object. The object is as follows:

```
export default [
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226752,
    "Amount": 55.95995977,
    "Total": 0.12689032
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226752,
    "Amount": 146.1,
    "Total": 0.33128467
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226684,
    "Amount": 150,
    "Total": 0.340026
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226684,
    "Amount": 26.79415765,
    "Total": 0.06073806
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226684,
    "Amount": 4.25269162,
    "Total": 0.00964017
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226659,
    "Amount": 25.79415765,
    "Total": 0.05846477
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00225784,
    "Amount": 4.48789501,
    "Total": 0.01013294
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226659,
    "Amount": 1,
    "Total": 0.00226659
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226663,
    "Amount": 225,
    "Total": 0.50999175
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226662,
    "Amount": 113.4736507,
    "Total": 0.25720164
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226659,
    "Amount": 26.79415765,
    "Total": 0.06073136
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226651,
    "Amount": 57.98798342,
    "Total": 0.13143034
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226649,
    "Amount": 40.19123647,
    "Total": 0.09109303
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00224958,
    "Amount": 11.83690383,
    "Total": 0.02662806
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00241238,
    "Amount": 838,
    "Total": 2.02157444
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00231078,
    "Amount": 9.95795791,
    "Total": 0.02301064
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.0025,
    "Amount": 4.1999832,
    "Total": 0.01049995
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.0025,
    "Amount": 4.99998,
    "Total": 0.01249995
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226702,
    "Amount": 3.63623022,
    "Total": 0.0082434
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226702,
    "Amount": 2.14933238,
    "Total": 0.00487257
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226702,
    "Amount": 15,
    "Total": 0.0340053
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00226702,
    "Amount": 56.80528353,
    "Total": 0.12877871
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00227634,
    "Amount": 76.88367619,
    "Total": 0.17501338
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.0000141,
    "Amount": 12444,
    "Total": 0.17546011
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.0000141,
    "Amount": 12131.09257,
    "Total": 0.1710484
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00001409,
    "Amount": 344.0847392,
    "Total": 0.00484815
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00249461,
    "Amount": 154.2853438,
    "Total": 0.38488176
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00249461,
    "Amount": 33.72938801,
    "Total": 0.08414166
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00246953,
    "Amount": 340.8737595,
    "Total": 0.84179797
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00246953,
    "Amount": 90.36231511,
    "Total": 0.22315244
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00246952,
    "Amount": 55.17093479,
    "Total": 0.13624572
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00246764,
    "Amount": 5.75660177,
    "Total": 0.01420522
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00245929,
    "Amount": 4.1587629,
    "Total": 0.0102276
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00252904,
    "Amount": 37.42985716,
    "Total": 0.0946616
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00252904,
    "Amount": 0.59310808,
    "Total": 0.00149999
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00252904,
    "Amount": 1.97703476,
    "Total": 0.00499999
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00252902,
    "Amount": 446.0229574,
    "Total": 1.12800097
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00252903,
    "Amount": 1.97704258,
    "Total": 0.00499999
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00259459,
    "Amount": 38.54173491,
    "Total": 0.09999999
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00259483,
    "Amount": 105.9381622,
    "Total": 0.27489152
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00259484,
    "Amount": 0.03853803,
    "Total": 0.0001
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00259484,
    "Amount": 0.03853803,
    "Total": 0.0001
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00259485,
    "Amount": 1.91102375,
    "Total": 0.00495881
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00259459,
    "Amount": 2,
    "Total": 0.00518918
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00259464,
    "Amount": 1.90549392,
    "Total": 0.00494407
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00259465,
    "Amount": 28.65568722,
    "Total": 0.07435147
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.01740491,
    "Amount": 0.20683711,
    "Total": 0.00359998
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00238916,
    "Amount": 79.70696671,
    "Total": 0.19043269
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00237524,
    "Amount": 37.90636505,
    "Total": 0.09003671
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00237524,
    "Amount": 2.00494017,
    "Total": 0.00476221
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00237524,
    "Amount": 18.57724489,
    "Total": 0.04412541
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00585,
    "Amount": 56.99961222,
    "Total": 0.33344773
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00585,
    "Amount": 0.00007739,
    "Total": 4.5e-7
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00585,
    "Amount": 0.00031039,
    "Total": 0.00000181
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 8.6e-7,
    "Amount": 2070,
    "Total": 0.0017802
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00187861,
    "Amount": 65.81153335,
    "Total": 0.1236342
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00187858,
    "Amount": 15.66747734,
    "Total": 0.0294326
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00187857,
    "Amount": 7.94470487,
    "Total": 0.01492468
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00187853,
    "Amount": 0.78814015,
    "Total": 0.00148054
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00187852,
    "Amount": 0.78814429,
    "Total": 0.00148054
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00054142,
    "Amount": 0.9975,
    "Total": 0.00054006
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 8.6e-7,
    "Amount": 811.9167491,
    "Total": 0.00069824
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 8.6e-7,
    "Amount": 338.0832509,
    "Total": 0.00029075
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00238719,
    "Amount": 72,
    "Total": 0.17187768
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00236363,
    "Amount": 4,
    "Total": 0.00945452
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00023501,
    "Amount": 41.1642077,
    "Total": 0.009674
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00023501,
    "Amount": 2.7697923,
    "Total": 0.00065092
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00000105,
    "Amount": 1270,
    "Total": 0.0013335
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00281001,
    "Amount": 360,
    "Total": 1.0116036
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00280001,
    "Amount": 3.33990832,
    "Total": 0.00935177
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.0038,
    "Amount": 208,
    "Total": 0.7904
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00356245,
    "Amount": 1,
    "Total": 0.00356245
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00370002,
    "Amount": 0.02702689,
    "Total": 0.0001
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00370002,
    "Amount": 15.4008193,
    "Total": 0.05698333
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00370002,
    "Amount": 3.09119995,
    "Total": 0.0114375
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.02315202,
    "Amount": 6.98549994,
    "Total": 0.16172843
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.02315202,
    "Amount": 6e-8,
    "Total": 0
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00023492,
    "Amount": 40,
    "Total": 0.0093968
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00004456,
    "Amount": 40.3006157,
    "Total": 0.00179579
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00004461,
    "Amount": 112.0824927,
    "Total": 0.00499999
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00004462,
    "Amount": 33.61721201,
    "Total": 0.00149999
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00004463,
    "Amount": 33.60967959,
    "Total": 0.0015
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.0002817,
    "Amount": 4,
    "Total": 0.0011268
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00003965,
    "Amount": 55.13060038,
    "Total": 0.00218592
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00003965,
    "Amount": 104.8693996,
    "Total": 0.00415807
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00004129,
    "Amount": 149.625,
    "Total": 0.00617801
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.02215591,
    "Amount": 3,
    "Total": 0.06646773
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00004073,
    "Amount": 113.3174137,
    "Total": 0.00461541
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00004072,
    "Amount": 36.68258634,
    "Total": 0.00149371
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.0000525,
    "Amount": 60,
    "Total": 0.00315
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.01877317,
    "Amount": 4,
    "Total": 0.07509268
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00199501,
    "Amount": 43.10755334,
    "Total": 0.08599999
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00350201,
    "Amount": 53.48162609,
    "Total": 0.18729318
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00350201,
    "Amount": 132.1260678,
    "Total": 0.46270681
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.02304826,
    "Amount": 17.03647964,
    "Total": 0.39266121
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.02312381,
    "Amount": 3.52,
    "Total": 0.08139581
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.02324002,
    "Amount": 3.39252036,
    "Total": 0.07884224
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.02459958,
    "Amount": 7,
    "Total": 0.17219706
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.01378499,
    "Amount": 9,
    "Total": 0.12406491
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00581178,
    "Amount": 1,
    "Total": 0.00581178
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.01498881,
    "Amount": 7,
    "Total": 0.10492167
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00001717,
    "Amount": 176.6891735,
    "Total": 0.00303375
  },
  {
    "Type": "Sell",
    "Price": 0.00001718,
    "Amount": 87.31082654,
    "Total": 0.00149999
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00001464,
    "Amount": 182.8870467,
    "Total": 0.00267746
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00001464,
    "Amount": 32.11295335,
    "Total": 0.00047013
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00596086,
    "Amount": 26,
    "Total": 0.15498236
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.000017,
    "Amount": 50,
    "Total": 0.00085
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.0005388,
    "Amount": 1,
    "Total": 0.0005388
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00935588,
    "Amount": 0.00060288,
    "Total": 0.00000564
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00935588,
    "Amount": 0.99939712,
    "Total": 0.00935023
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.01475001,
    "Amount": 1,
    "Total": 0.01475001
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00555,
    "Amount": 21.28693846,
    "Total": 0.1181425
  },
  {
    "Type": "Buy",
    "Price": 0.00553,
    "Amount": 9.26025155,
    "Total": 0.05120919
  }
]
```

I was shown how to print the values:

```
_renderData(){
     const data = this.state.sdc
     return Object.keys(data).map(function(key,index){
         const datum = data[key]
         return ( <div key={datum.id}>
          <p>Type: {datum.Type}</p>
          <p>Price: {datum.Price}</p>
          <p>Amount: {datum.Amount}</p>
          <p>Total: {datum.Total}</p>
        </div> )
     })
  }
```

Now I'm trying to play with it, eg:

```
_extractData() {
    const data = this.state.sdc
    return Object.keys(data[0])

  }
```

Will print the four headers (Type, Price, Amount, Total) but I really want to do some more complicated things. eg.

- Display all transactions of a type: Buy
- Display all transactions with total value greater than x, etc.

How would I access all those. Can you provide an example, please?

EDIT: I've added one method suggested below - however it does not display anything:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from './header/header';
import Body from './body/body';
import sdc from './data';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    // Set the initial grid in
    this.state = {
      title: "Singularity is nigh!!!",
      sdc: sdc
    };

  }

  _renderData(){
     const data = this.state.sdc
     return Object.keys(data).map(function(key,index){
         const datum = data[key]
         return ( <div key={datum.id}>
          <p>Type: {datum.Type}</p>
          <p>Price: {datum.Price}</p>
          <p>Amount: {datum.Amount}</p>
          <p>Total: {datum.Total}</p>
        </div> )
     })
  }


  _extractData() {
    const data = this.state.sdc
    return Object.keys(data[0])

  }

  _renderBuy() {
    const data = this.state.sdc
    data.filter(function(element) {
      return element.hasOwnProperty("Type") && element.Type == 'Buy';
  });

  }

  render() {
    const renderedData = this._renderBuy()


    return (
      // Add your component markup and other subcomponent references here.
      <div>
        <Header title={this.state.title} />
        {renderedData}    
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: It's an array of objects.

Comment: So it's nothing to do with JSON, right?

Comment: Right. JSON is a **textual** data representation, just like XML, YAML or CSV. See also [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is more like a general javascript question. What you are asking for is to filter the list of objects from your array, and so a way to achieve that is by using the array's [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
// Filter all the transactions of type 'Buy'
data.filter(function(element) { 
  return element.hasOwnProperty("Type") && element.Type == 'Buy'; 
});

// Filter all the transactions having a total amount greater than or equal to 0.84
data.filter(function(element) { 
  return element.hasOwnProperty("Total") && element.Total >= 0.84; 
});
```

The output you get from the `filter` is just a new array of objects with the elements that pass the test, so in order to render them in React you would need to traverse this new returned array, just like you did in your `_renderData()` instance method.

I've made some slight changes to your `_renderData` method so that it accepts an argument, which would be any array of objects so you don't have to repeat the same code again to render the "Buy" transactions, or any other filtered array.

```
_renderData(data){
   return Object.keys(data).map(function(key,index){
       const datum = data[key]
       return ( <div key={datum.id}>
        <p>Type: {datum.Type}</p>
        <p>Price: {datum.Price}</p>
        <p>Amount: {datum.Amount}</p>
        <p>Total: {datum.Total}</p>
      </div> )
   })
}

render() {
  const renderedData = this._renderData(this._renderBuy());

  return (
    // Add your component markup and other subcomponent references here.
    <div>
      <Header title={this.state.title} />
      {renderedData}    
    </div>

  );
};
```

[jsBin](https://jsbin.com/lumuzuv/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thanks but it does not display anything - see above - I've added the code with the first method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you  for clarification and the code - unfortunately I still get an error: App.js?98ef:18Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: My bad, there was an unneeded closing parenthesis at the end of the render function. Edited my answer and added a jsBin link to it to make sure it works.